# How do I throw a custom exception on unauthorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following implementation.

My exception middleware:

```
public class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _env;

    public ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions(RequestDelegate next, IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _next = next;
        _env = env;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, _env);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, IHostEnvironment _env)
    {
        HttpStatusCode status;
        string message;
        var stackTrace = String.Empty;

        var exceptionType = exception.GetType();
        if (exceptionType == typeof(BadRequestException))
        {
            message = exception.Message;
            status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        else if (exceptionType == typeof(NotFoundException))
        {
            message = exception.Message;
            status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        else
        {
            status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            message = exception.Message;
            if (_env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
                stackTrace = exception.StackTrace;
        }

        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { title = "Error", error = message, stackTrace });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)status;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

but my problem is the [Authorize] attribute isn't throwing exceptions it just returns 401. Thing is it's basically the same as any exception in my application, I would at least like to treat them similar. How can I return the 401 unauthorized with the Title, Error, Stacktrace properties instead of just a 401?

Edit, Here's the coontroller that uses Authorize:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("{organizationId}/[controller]")]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    
}
```

and here's my auth:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };
            });

        return services;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot find "Authorize" anywhere in your posted code.  Can you please post the missing code so we can discern context a little better?

Comment: @CorneliusJ.vanDyk I have added a bit more code. That's basically all there is to the problem.